# How to generate labels, buttons, Checkboxes and textboxes dynamically in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dynamically-generated

I am a newbie in WPF. I am following MVVM pattern. I have listbox in my mainwindow which has list of items. I also have a grid which is empty on startup. Now here is the query, on selecting the item from listbox, I want to generate labels, buttons, Checkboxes and textboxes dynamically rather than using toolbox.

**ListBox & Grid in MainWindow:**

```
<ListBox Name="ButtonPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding BoardTabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="0,27,0,0" Content="{Binding TabName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Grid Height="461" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="139,0,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="339" >

</Grid>
```

**TabName** is as string which is part of my model class.

**ViewModel Class:**

```
public List<Product> m_BoardTabs; 
public ProductViewModel()
{       
    m_BoardTabs = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product() {TabName = "A"}, 
        new Product() {TabName = "B"},
        new Product() {TabName = "C"},               
    };
}                      

public List<Product> BoardTabs
{
    get
    {
        return m_BoardTabs;
    }

    set
    {
        m_BoardTabs = value;
    }
}

private Product m_SelectedItem;
public Product SelectedTab
{
    get
    {
        return m_SelectedItem;
    }

    set
    {
        m_SelectedItem = value;                
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
    }
}
```

**Demonstration:**

ListBox has 3 items. A, B, C

On selecting A, in my grid, I want to display L1, L2, L3 in stack order. B1, B2, B3 in stack order, C1, C2, C3 and T1, T2, T3 so on, where L is label, B is button, T is textbox and C is checkbox.

On selecting B, in my grid, I want to display L5, L6, L7 in stack order. B5, B6, B7 in stack order, C5, C6, C7 and T5, T6, T7 so on, where L is label, B is button, T is textbox and C is checkbox.

Same with Selecting C. Although its easy to create labels in application with the help of toolbox.

Is there a way I can generate them inside the grid based on selected item from Listbox?

Comment: do L1,B1,C1,T1 are related to a model ? (what they refer to)

Comment: No. I am not sure. Auto generatin of these UI components is what I wanna know how to do. Although i know the implementatin using toolbox but generating dynamically is were I am helpless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

What you need is different `DataTemplates` for each case where you can define the structure of your desired controls and a `DataTemplateSelector` to set the actual template for your `Grid`.

Find more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

Comment: Balogh: Thanks :) Are der any other code/demo app which can help me?

Comment: Well I searched online but looks like this is a rare case in WPF. Still not able to figure out how can I achieve this :(